# LoadError: cannot load such file — bcrypt_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, bcrypt

I have tried to deploy devise authentication on my rails app.

I am getting this issue

"cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext"

I see it is a common issue amongst windows based computers but the answers to other questions have not helped me yet.

I am running Windows 8 x64 with x86 ruby and devkit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bcrypt\_ext. so (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014317/bcrypt-ext-so-loaderror)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
C:\> gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bcrypt
C:\> cd (path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> ruby extconf.rb
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make install
```

reference: https://www.alib.jp/entries/bcrypt_ext_load_error_on_ruby21x

Comment: I tried that. When i type in "make" i get its not a recognized command

Comment: if you have downloaded ruby devkit, make should be included. Run the file `devkitvars.bat` which is in the devkit install folder. It will configure the correct environment for ruby devkit. Then run `make` and `make install` should work.

Comment: i did run devkitvars.bat right after downloading the devkit. make still doesnt work

Comment: Have you added the devkit/bin and devkit/mingw/bin paths to your PATH var?

Comment: is the name of the variable "PATH"?

Comment: This allows you to all make in your command prompt.
Then cd into your gem dir and type make. This will build the makefile.

Comment: can you please tell me what var's to add to my env var

Comment: `C:\<Current Folder> C:\<DevKit Path>\devkitvars.bat`

Comment: remember to restart server after `make install`

Comment: now im getting this error:

There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'

Comment: that should be a separate error. Is your make working now?

Comment: yes my make is working however my server wont start since it says it cant load the uglifier gem

Comment: coool! have u restarted the server yet?

Comment: i havent been able to start it since my make started working. and the server was off while during the process of running make

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how to deal with the uglifier gem. I havent encountered that. You may need to create a new post and ask for someone's help since I can only help with loading bcrypt_ext... I am sorry about that :(

Comment: On **Ruby on Rails5** the **Devkit** is inside the c:\RailsInstaller folder <br/> **Gem Path:** C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bcrypt-‌​3.1.11-x86-mingw32\e‌​xt\mri

Comment: still not working in rails 5 getting "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32/ruby/config.h:168:15: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 #define uid_t int" this error while running make command

Comment: I get https://pastebin.com/raw/ZQBqYLTH    `make: *** No rule to make target` `/C/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h', needed by` `bcrypt_ext.o'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt_ext.so file is missing -if you manually copy it to proper folder - in my case \Ruby23\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32\lib - it helps. :)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include proper sentences?  Makes it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: where to copy this file ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

-Uninstall all bcrypt versions: gem uninstall bcrypt

select option 3 (uninstall all)

-Uninstall all bcrypt-ruby versions: gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby

select option 3 (uninstall all)

replace the line in your gemfile by:

to add this line to the gemfile:
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby

did not work for me though but to point the gemfile to the git repository did:

gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'

bundle install

and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

At this link  https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

Somebody mentioned this solution

```
gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

And it worked for me